# How to search and replace in epub file opened with vim.zip

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Adding a simple line to my .vimrc I managed to open an ePub archive with zip.vim on a vim buffer. This basically opens a numbered list of htm, css, jpg, xml files that one can access individually. I want to perform a search and replace through all these numbered files as it is too painful to edit each of them and do it - there's around 400 files. :args and :argdo did not really work or at least I could not make them. Any ideas?

Comment: `:bufdo` to run a command in all loaded buffers?

Comment: it does not seem to work because I don't really have all the 400 files open in a buffer. It's hard for me to tell what it is and how all files are loaded, you should try to open an ePub if you have the time. Thanks for your attempt anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it will work for you, and I'm going to assume that when you hit Enter on a filepath inside your Vim buffer, a new viewport is opened (by the `ZipBrowseSelect()` function defined in `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/zip.vim`) to display the contents of the file.

If this is the case, you could try the following method.

```
:%argd
```

This command deletes all the paths in the current arglist.
Then, you would have to visually select all the lines containing a path to a file you want to modify. From normal mode, you could hit `vip`, for example, and adjust the visual selection to exclude some lines if needed.

```
:'<,'>g/^/exe "norm \r" | argadd % | close
```

This command should hit Enter on each line inside your visual selection, add the file which has been opened in a new viewport, and close the latter to get back to the original window.

```
:vim /pattern/ ##
```

This command should populate the quickfix list with all the lines containing the pattern you're looking for.

```
:cfdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

This command should replace `pattern` with `replacement` in each file present in the quickfix list, and save the file if it has been changed.

---

The last step uses the `:cfdo` command which was introduced in Vim version [7.4.858](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/aa23b379421aa214e6543b06c974594a25799b09). If your Vim version is not new enough to support `:cfdo`, you could bypass the last 2 steps, and directly execute:

```
:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

The benefit of:

```
:vim /pattern/ ##
:cfdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

... is to prune the arglist from the files which don't contain your pattern, so that the substitutions commands are only executed when needed.

If you don't have `:cfdo` but still want to prune the arglist, you could source this custom command:

```
com! -nargs=0 -bar Qargs exe 'args '.s:qfl_names()
fu! s:qfl_names() abort
    let buffer_numbers = {}
    for qf_item in getqflist()
        let buffer_numbers[qf_item['bufnr']] = bufname(qf_item['bufnr'])
    endfor
    return join(map(values(buffer_numbers), 'fnameescape(v:val)'))
endfu
```

I've copied it from this video:  [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/).
Most of the other commands are also taken from this video, so it might help you to have a look at it, if you don't have already.

Then, you would replace the `:cfdo` command, with:

```
:Qargs
:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

---

To summarize, you could try one of these 3 methods:

```
:%argd
visually select the paths of the files
:'<,'>g/^/exe "norm \r" | argadd % | close
:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

Or:

```
:%argd
visually select the paths of the files
:'<,'>g/^/exe "norm \r" | argadd % | close
:vim /pattern/ ##
:cfdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

Or:

```
:%argd
visually select the paths of the files
:'<,'>g/^/exe "norm \r" | argadd % | close
:vim /pattern/ ##
:Qargs
:argdo %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update
```

---

Edit:

You could also try to visually select the paths of the files, then execute:

```
:'<,'>g/^/e `='zipfile:'.expand('%:p').'::'.getline(".")` | %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update | b#
```

This method relies on the fact that the path to a file in the archive seems to follow this scheme:

```
zipfile:/path/to/epub::path/to/file/in/archive
```

So, you can get the path to a file under the cursor with the Vim expression:

```
'zipfile:'.expand('%:p').'::'.getline(".")
```

And you can edit this file using backticks (see `` :h `= ``):

```
:e `=Vim expression`
→
:e `='zipfile:'.expand('%:p').'::'.getline(".")`
```

From there, you need the global command, to repeat the edition on each line inside the visual selection.

In the [epub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765382032) I tested, all the paths were below the line `mimetype`. If this is the case for you, then you could merge the 2 steps (visual selection + global command) in a single command:

```
1/mimetype/+,$g/^/e `='zipfile:'.expand('%:p').'::'.getline(".")` | %s/pattern/replacement/ge | update | b#
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the very articulate answer. Each method hinges on the :%argd command; however when I launch it and proceed to the visual selection and then press Enter I get several error messages: 
E121: Undefined variable b:zipfile
E15: Invalid expresson: b:zipfile
E121: Undefined variable: zipfile
E116: Invalid arguments for fiction fnameescape("zip file:".zipfile.'::'.fname)
E15: Invalid expression:"e ".fnameescape("zipfile:".zipfile/'::'.fname).
This happens every time I try to select more than one file.

Comment: @Dalamar I'm not sure to understand, but just to be sure, you shouldn't hit Enter once you've visually selected your paths. You should just hit colon (`:`), to go from visual mode to command-line mode. When you do that, Vim should automatically populate the command-line with the visual range `'<,'>`. (You could remove it if you want, because I included it inside the examples.) From there, you would have to add (or copy-paste) a global command. For example, `g/^/exe "norm \r" | argadd % | close`.

Comment: @Dalamar What matters at the end, is that you execute the global command with the visual range in front of it `'<,'>g/^/...`. I also added 2 other possible methods you could try, at the end, one of which doesn't require that you visually select anything. They may be much simpler than the previous ones (because they only involve one or 2 commands). They all worked on my machine, but I can't assure you it will work for you, because I don't know which Vim version you're using, which zip plugin version is installed, and what epub you're working on.

Comment: @Dalamar Also, if you still have some errors when executing one command, it may come from your custom configuration (it happened for me). In this case, you could start Vim with a minimum of initializations: `vim -Nu NORC /path/to/epub`

Comment: I have version 8. If I was to search and delete a line that contains a certain string would changing the last line in your second solution to
:argdo g/pattern/d | update  do the trick?

Comment: @Dalamar I suppose it would, but there's a problem because the global command would interpret the pipe as a part of its argument. It means it would save the file every time it would delete a line. If it's a problem, you could hide `|update` from `g` like this: `argdo exe 'g/pattern/d_' | update`. The underscore is to not pollute your default register (the deleted text will go into the black hole register).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but this mìght help you

On esc mode try

```
:%s/word you want to search/word you want yo replace with/g
```

Comment: No, sorry, this only work on one open file, thanks anyway